# Find $dy/dx$ for $y =\operatorname{arcsec}(\tan x)$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, inverse-function

If $$y =\operatorname{arcsec}(\tan x),$$ then find $\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}$.

Note: I was practising on finding derivatives for various types of questions and I stumbled upon the question mentioned above.
I solved it and my answer came out to be :
$$\frac{{(\sec x)^2}}{{\tan x \cdot \tan(\operatorname{arcsec}(\tan x))}}$$

I couldn't move further after this expression.

However, the options provided for this question were :

a) $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

b) $$-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

c) $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

d) none

And the correct option mentioned in the book is option (a). I don't seem to understand how option (a) is given as the answer to this question.

Please help me in understanding how option (a) will be the solution. Is the answer different to option (a) ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please use latex for this website: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hint: The chain rule is your friend here. You can also make the work easiser by drawing a reference triangle.

Comment: I did follow the chain rule but couldn't get the answer. I don't have any idea on how to reach the answer. Looking forward to your help everyone.

Comment: Unless it's $y=\sec(\arctan x)$ instead of $y=\mathrm{arcsec}(\tan x )$, it ain't gonna work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in order the get correct option
$$y=sec(\arctan(x))$$
$$tan(z)=x$$
Using pythagorean theorem
$$sec(z)=\sqrt{x^2+1}$$
$$z=arcsec(\sqrt{x^2+1})$$
$$z=arctan{x}$$
So
$$y=sec(z)$$
$$y=sec(arcsec(\sqrt{x^2+1})$$
$$y=\sqrt{x^2+1}$$
$$y'=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

Comment: It should be y= arcsec(tanx). The provided solution has taken y=sec(arctanx). Does this mean that to get to the correct option y=sec(arctanx) should be taken and not the other way round as mentioned originally?

Comment: @pythagoras y should be equal to sec(arctan(x)), else it isn't possible to get desired result.